# How to run a command line utility instead of WebServlet in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a fairly standard Spring Boot app. We are now in a phase of performance testing the application. In order to do this, we need to generate a large set of request objects from a mocking library. The end point uses protobufs, so they need to be dumped into a file and saved for Jmeter. I would like to add some sort of command line functionality to my application to have it generate the performance test assets only.

I have tried things like:

```
java -cp target/sm-reports-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.blah.reportservice.AssetGenerator
```

or

```
java -Dloader.main=com.blah.reportservice..AssetGenerator -jar target/sm-reports-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

While having the functionality in an alternative main class. None of this quite seems to work. Due to the architecture of the parent project here in the company, a module style approach would be a ton of work.

Is there a good way or place to accomplish this? Do I switch on the ApplicaitonBuilder configuration before main on some flag or variable? In an ideal world I would be able to run something like the above with a command line flag to have ti accomplish what I am looking for. Can anyone help or point me int he right direction in the docs?

Comment: what i have done in the past to bootstrap data is using a `CommandLineRunner` class annotated with a `@Profile`.  So this code only gets executed there, once it's part of the profile.

Comment: You haven't really said what doesn't work. Is your jar packaged with Spring Boot? Does it have the`PropertiesLauncher` as a main (your second example suggests this)?

Comment: @DaveSyer "What doesn't work": At the moment, I can't even get an alternative main class to run. If I attempt to run the alternative main via the "-cp" flag route, I get error messages like:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/468529d4c36934aef1c6

Comment: @DaveSyer In the other example, using the -Dloader.main=.. It still picks up the main of regular spring-boot Webservlet class used to start the web-app as normal. Now that class does have to be defined in the pom as a property "start-class" since otherwise the jar won't build. It error's out and says it can't determine which "main" to use.

I do not have a PropertiesLauncher created anywhere that I know of.

Comment: Well 'loader.main' is a feature of the `PropertiesLauncher`. Look it up in the maven plugin docs.